# css: make half a a square like in the image

Tags: css

I was wondering if it would be possible to make half a square like the one I point to in the image using only css:
[image]

Comment: You can create 4 empty elements in your square (each one for a corner), then use ::before and ::after on each element to create green lines.

Comment: To use only CSS look into linear gradients as background images.